# How to create web page with grid view of top news

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working in VisualStudio 2010 C#. I want to create a web page that has top news stories with an image each and the image would be a hyperlink that takes you to the full story. I have posted a picture example of how I would like it to look. I already have my master page created, and I don't want to know about import the files for the news story or images from the database or anything, just the basics of how to create this kind of layout. Thanks!!
example of how I want it to look:
http://www.aol.com/news/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this great free CSS library: http://metroui.org.ua/. It has similar look and feel to what you posted, so you can just style your GridView with the classes provided there.